# How do I move an object in a square pattern?

Tags: javascript, math

I have some bots that can move via setting the x and y. I have already been able to make them move in a circle pattern, but how do I make them rotate in a square pattern? I'm not very good at math, so I'd appreciate some help.

here is how I did circle pattern.

```
var PI2 = 2 * Math.PI, FOLLOWADD = PI2 / 18/*PI2 / 360 * 20*/, BOTSLICE = PI2 / BOTS;

bots.follow = function(id) {
    if (!ppl()[id])
        id = protocol.id; //player is default

    var pos = getPos(id), a, i = BOTS;
    while (i--)
        if (this[i] && !this.busy) {
            a = BOTSLICE * i + f;
          this[i].pos.x = pos.x + (Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / BOTS * i + f) * 3);
            this[i].pos.y = pos.y + (Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / BOTS * i + f) * 3);
        }
    f = (f + FOLLOWADD) % PI2;
}.bind(bots);
```

Comment: include so code to show what you've tried so far

Comment: Can you provide an illustration to show what you are trying to do? You can use Paint or a similar program to draw some screens.

Comment: ok i added some of my code.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "rotate in a square pattern". Rotation doesn't make sharp turns but going around the outside of a square does.

Comment: basically, this program makes a bunch of bots rotate around a user. Right now, it rotates in a circle pattern. Here is what it looks like right now: [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/498579130699481119/542123138532638722/unknown.png)

Comment: f = frame, a = angle?

Comment: yep that's right, i think.

Comment: Do mean "move in a square pattern"? Because as mentioned above, rotation is by definition circular, and it's always a good idea to use as exact a phrasing as possible, so that people don't get the wrong idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the angle and the shortest distance to the imaginary square track you can make a triangle. One vertex is the player, one is the bot, and the other is where the shortest distance from the player to the track intersects the track.

This snippet is kind of a proof of concept for you, you'll probably be able to just use the position calculations and drop them into your code with your variables, I just used longer names to try to make it easier to read.

```js
const player = $( '#player' );
const bot = $( '.bot' );

const radius = 50; // this is the shortest distance from the center to the edge
const numSteps = 180;
const eigthOfCircle = ( Math.PI * 2 ) / 8;
const angleStepSize = Math.PI * 2 / numSteps; // split the circle into steps.

let angle = 0;

setInterval( function() {
  let xPlayer = player.offset().left;
  let yPlayer = player.offset().top;
  
  let x = 0, y = 0;
  
  if ( angle < eigthOfCircle || angle > eigthOfCircle * 7 ) {
    y = - radius + 15;
    x = Math.sin( angle ) * radius;
  }
  else if ( angle < eigthOfCircle * 3 ) {
    x = radius - 15;
    y = - Math.cos( angle ) * radius;
  }
  else if ( angle < eigthOfCircle * 5 ) {
    y = radius - 15;
    x = Math.sin( angle ) * radius;
  }
  else if ( angle < eigthOfCircle * 7) {
    x = - radius + 15;
    y = - Math.cos( angle ) * radius;
  }
  
  bot.css( { 
    left: xPlayer + x + 'px', 
    top: yPlayer + y + 'px',
  });
  
  angle += angleStepSize;
  angle = angle > Math.PI * 2 ? 0 : angle;
  
  console.log( xPlayer, yPlayer, angle, Math.sin( angle ), Math.cos( angle ) );
}, 20 );
```

```css
#player {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}

.bot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<div class="bot"></div>
```